# UnexpectedValueException · GET / - Invalid Host

Tags: php, laravel-4, digital-ocean

I published my laravel app via Laravel Forge to DigitalOcean, and am now getting slammed with the following:

```
UnexpectedValueException · GET /
Invalid Host "*.piuandme.info"

STAGE
staging

URL
http://*.piuandme.info/

Stacktrace summary

index.php:49 · [main]
```

It's coming from the following 3 hosts, all in China:

- http://*.piuandme.info/
- http://*.lleiiell.info/
- http://*.weinisishuicheng.com/

Any idea what is causing this and how to prevent it? I have multiple other Laravel apps up and running on DigitalOcean published the same way on different droplets with no issues.

**Update:** This issue has resolved itself, and seemed to have been DNS related, as well as my server not configured to ignore requests that don't match my domain names.

Comment: Sorry Mike, these are my domains, but i don't know why you get slammed, is my vps hacked?

Comment: Hi Sean, did you move away from DigitalOcean, or move to different DO servers at the time of this post? I think the issue was twofold: your DNS records seem to have still been pointing to the DO IP address (that I inherited), and my web server was not returning 404 errors to requests where the domain didn't match. It seems to have resolved itself about a week after I posted this.

Comment: Cool, you had resolved it, and yes i moved to linode several months ago. Sorry for you had gotten slammed.